# Frechet Derivative and Convergence of Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, calculus-of-variations, parabolic-pde

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval, $\{u_{n}(t)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a bounded sequence in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ and define $J[u_{n}(t)] = \frac{1}{2}||u_{n}(t)||_{H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)}^{2}-\frac{1}{p}||u_{n}(t)||_{p}^{p}$ such that $\frac{d}{dt}J[u_{n}(t_{1})] \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for $t_{1} \in [0,\infty)$ and $2<p<\infty$.

By the property of Hilbert Space, we can have a subsequence $\{u_{n_{k}}(t_{1})\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $u_{n_{k}(t_{1})}\to v$ weakly in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$.

Let $J'[u_{n}(t_{1})]$ be the Frechet derivative of $J[u_{n}(t_{1})]$. Can I obtain $J'[u_{n}(t_{1})]\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$?

For your information, the functional $J[\,\cdot\,]$ is related to the following semilinear pde ($2<p<\infty$)
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
u_{t} = \Delta u-u+u|u|^{p-2} &\text{ in }\Omega\times(0,\infty)\\
u(\cdot,0) = u_{0} &\text{ in }\Omega\\
u(0,t) = u(b,t)= 0 &\text{ in }(0,\infty)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I am trying to obtain strong convergence in $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ from weak convergence but I need $J'[u_{n}(t_{1})]\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ in order to do it.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you very much!